# UnityShaderCompiler symbol lookup error on Ubuntu

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to run the latest Unity LTS (2021.3.3f1) on Ubuntu 20.04, but the editor is refusing the launch with this error:

> Shader compiler initialization error: Failed to get ipc connection from UnityShaderCompiler shader compiler! /home/me/Desktop/Unity/2021.3.3f1/Editor/Data/Tools/UnityShaderCompiler

However, when I try to run `UnityShaderCompiler` directly from the command line, I get:

```
./UnityShaderCompiler: symbol lookup error: ./UnityShaderCompiler: undefined symbol: _ZN10IDxcResult13IDxcResult_IDE
```

Which, when passed to `c++filt`, gives me

```cpp
IDxcResult::IDxcResult_ID
```

I can't find any clues based off of the symbol name; I get a few references to Direct X and some documentation for a [rust struct](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Graphics/Direct3D/Dxc/struct.IDxcResult.html) with the same name, but `IDxcResult_ID` doesn't seem to exist anywhere.

Does anybody have any clue how I might go about solving this? I also have a Unity 2019.3.6f1 install that works flawlessly though.